# How to format a line Break (VBCrLf)

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the following code and want to do two things. I would like to separate the two W.writeLine codes by one or two lines. VbCrlf doesn't seem to work I get errors. I would also like to change the color of Total Due and TotalDueTextBox.Text to red. Any Suggestions?

```
  Private Sub SaveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveAsToolStripMenuItem.Click
    sFile.InitialDirectory = ("C:\")
    sFile.FileName = ("Save As...")
    sFile.Filter = ("Only Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt")
    sFile.ShowDialog()

    Dim W As New IO.StreamWriter(sFile.FileName, True)  ' notes from class need messgbox
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To PurchaseListBox.Items.Count - 1
        W.WriteLine(PurchaseListBox.Items.Item(i))

    Next

    Dim TotalDue As String = TotalDueTextBox.Text
    W.WriteLine(vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "TotalDue" & TotalDueTextBox.Text.PadLeft(14, ""))
    W.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you get? There should be no reason not to use `VbCrLf`. You can always use it's framework equivalent, `Environment.NewLine`

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `WriteLine("")` each time you want to print a blank line.